# Jenkins slow executing job

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, jenkins, amazon-ec2

I have a Jenkins job that kicks off a BASH script on an AWS instance.
The job is fairly simple and does a few standard commands such as copying files, creating directories etc...
This script is called using a simple "execute shell" step.

When I run the BASH script directly in a shell (both locally and on AWS) it runs in less than a minute. However when I run it via Jenkins it can take a few minutes to complete. When I watch the console output I can see the commands being executed but I can also see that there are significant delays occurring between each command. Like it waits a few seconds before executing the next command.

I've checked file permissions and they are all fine.

Any ideas?

Comment: Is there a specific command that run much slower or all the commands runs slower ...

Comment: hhhmmm, I've just noticed that this primarily occurs on new EC2 instances. They are spun up by Jenkins using the EC2 plugin and the job runs - albeit slowly. If I rerun the job after it finishes it runs in a reasonable/expected time.

Comment: Any chance it's cache issue , first run copy some files that second run use without copy ? Can you share your script ?

Comment: I think this may be my issue... http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ebs-initialize.html

Comment: You can verify by spin up a new machine and run your script manually

Comment: Yep the issue was the AWS warmup described in the link above. Thanks everyone